# How can I reduce syntactic clutter when tagging a polymorphic tree in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

So I want a type that represents trees containing a set of node-types. I would also like types that represent similar tree defined over overlapping sets. This is another version of the Typed AST problem. Say that my pool of node-types is:

```
data Lit = Lit Int
data Var = Var String
data Hole = Hole Int
```

A parse-tree can contain `Lit`s or `Var`s but no `Hole`s. A second kind tree called a template can contain `Lit`s, `Var`s or `Hole`s.

To keep things simple there is a single type of recursive node called `Add`.

```
data Parse = A Lit | B Var
data Template = C Lit | D Var | E Hole
data Tree a = Leaf a 
            | Add (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

So now I can declare data, and I can still pattern-match on it, the only problem is the syntactic clutter.

```
aParse = Add (A Lit 3) (B Var "x")
aTemplate = Add (C Lit 4) (E Hole 3)
fun (Add (A lit) (B var) = ...
```

What I would like is some sugar similar to :

```
ParseLit = A . Lit
TempLit = C . Lit
```

Obviously aliases for compositions of constructors (not types) is not legal in Haskell. But what is the cleanest way to write this, avoiding as much boiler-plate as possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`PatternSynonyms`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html) language extension can help here. It lets you specify aliases for patterns:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

pattern ParseLit x = A (Lit x)

someFunc :: Parse -> Int
someFunc p = case p of
    ParseLit x -> x
    _ -> 0
```

There are two flavors of pattern synonyms: bidirectional (like in the example) and unidirectional. The bidirectional ones can also be used as constructors:

```
*Main> :t ParseLit
ParseLit :: Int -> Parse

*Main> ParseLit 77
```